# Unexpected error within json babel 6.9

Tags: json, babeljs

Setting up babel cli and preset 2015.  I am getting an unexepected error though

```
.babelrc: Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected 'e'
at JSON5.parse.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:50:25)
```

My babel file **.bablelrc**

for now is set up like

```
 echo '{ "presets": ["es2015"] }' > .babelrc
```

My dev dependencies are set up like so

```
"devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.9.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0"
```

}

not seeing the error in the babel rc file any insight would be much appreciated

Comment: That's definitely a weird one. Are you sure you don't have some second `.babelrc` somewhere else that might be getting picked up?

Comment: I did a global search and found the other reference here:   node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/config.js.

Comment: Sorry I mean, are you sure that `.babelrc` is the one that cases the issue? If you have one in some other folder, perhaps that one is broken? If you delete your `.babelrc` for instance, does the error change?

Comment: Deleting the babelrc file definitely removes the error.  I can get everything to work fine on bash "babel src --presets es2015 --out-file build/bundle.js -w -s
".   As soon as I use the babelrc file and remove the presets off the command line everything returns to the error message.

Comment: If you open the `.babelrc` in the editor, it's exactly the JSON, right? The `e` in the error message makes me worry `echo` is actually ending up inside the file somehow.

Comment: checked it again.  Copied and pasted it off the babel website.  Makes sense though.  I am able to run the command I noted above and list plugins inside of babel.rc at this point.  Babel is not liking what I was doing above with that echo command.

Comment: I had the same error, that was caused on Windows 10 by running `echo {"presets": ["react"]} > .babelrc` which apparently leaves some invisible characters in the file or weird encoding. When created in the editor, the file worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on Windows 7, I used PowerShell to put in the commands. Anyways the encoding for the index.js and .babelrc files were both something called UCS-2 BE BOM. So I changed the encoding for both files to UTF-8 and they both worked. Hopefully that helps.

It probably had something to do with invisible characters or whatever. Anyways in the future I'll probably avoid doing Linux-like commands on Windows.

Comment: Good comment, but since the original poster's question had nothing to do with PowerShel, I would say that this type of response in the future should be a "Comment", instead of an "Answer".

Comment: That doesn't really matter since the question was a mystery. I got a similar error and fixed it by changing the file encoding.

Comment: Solved my issue. I created the file by running "echo "" > .babelrc" on win10. This creates the encoding to UCS-2 BE BOM for some reason.